# Linux: How to get a string of three characters within a file name?

Tags: linux, printf

I have hundreds of file names formatted such as:

```
3016-002+26797_+20220428+142340+0000000002+0000000001+0000000028.dcmzzz
3016-002+26797_+20220428+142340+0000000002+0000000001+0000000240.dcmzzz
3016-002+26797_+20220428+142340+0000000002+0000000001+0000000372.dcmzzz
```

I want to get only the first three numbers before the ".dcmzzz" extension, so in this case, I would be left with 028, 240, and 372 (making sure to keep that leading zero if it's a two-digit number). I am thinking it might have something to do with printf, but I am not sure how to format this. Would anybody have a suggestion as to how to accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: There are tons of options out there. awk, grep and sed, to name a few.

Comment: `sed` is probably the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

Please run on the directory where the files are:

```
ls | grep -oP '\d{3}(?=\.dcmzzz)'
```

**Output:**

```
028
240
372
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only bash

```
for n in 3016*; do echo "${n: -10: 3}"; done
```

Comment: May be worth explaining the space before `-10` in `: -10` is mandatory or it must be in parenthesis `:(-10)`. For positive values it doesn't matter.

Comment: Right, not to be confused with `${var:-val}` (default value)

Comment: I also like the use of a builtin, if available. Much better than spawning the additional subshells for large data sets. But without string indexes, your are left with the old `${var%.dcmzzz}` and `${var##*+}` and then an `expr substr ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can round out the collection of ways with `sed`. Simply pipe the directory listing to the `sed` expression.

If using *Basic Regular Expressions* (BRE), you can do:

```bash
ls | sed 's/^.*\([0-9]\{3\}\).dcmzzz$/\1/'
```

With *Extended Regular Expressions* (ERE) you can avoid escaping the backreference group and the repetition,

```bash
ls | sed -E 's/^.*([0-9]{3}).dcmzzz$/\1/'
```

In both cases the output is what you request, e.g.

```
$ ls | sed -E 's/^.*([0-9]{3}).dcmzzz$/\1/'
028
240
372
```

Works with POSIX and advanced shells.